# Type 'Promise<typeof PublicModule>' is not assignable to type 'LoadChildrenCallback'

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-router

I am doing lazy loading in the angular app. but I am getting an error while importing the module in loadChildren.

I'm using angular 13. It was simple in angular 8 where I just import the module by using string.

I also tried import using string but it gives another error like **Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'LoadChildrenCallback'**

[image]

here are the codes below.

**PublicRoutingModule**

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router'
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class PublicRoutingModule {
}
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {PublicModule} from "../OtherModules/public-module/public.module";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    loadChildren: import('../OtherModules/public-module/public.module').then(({PublicModule}) => PublicModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**PublicModule**

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {PublicRoutingModule}from "./public-routing.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    PublicRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    PublicRoutingModule,
  ]
})
export class PublicModule {
}
```

**AppModule**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {PublicModule} from '../OtherModules/public-module/public.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The documentation specifies you need to assign a function that returns the resolved module for Routes with dynamic imports: not the import statement directly. https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-basics

Comment: How did I miss that. Thanks.

Comment: Comment by @Terry should do the trick however apart from that I see that - From you module files, I see `import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';` this import as missing. Is that just a typo?

Comment: It is there in my code, I just missed copying this line. By the way, "loadchildren" takes function. I was just providing the import directly. The import should be wrapped in a function. that was my mistake.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to pass a function to loadChildren.

**wrong:**

```
loadChildren: import('../OtherModules/public-module/public.module').then(({PublicModule}) => PublicModule)
```

**Correct:**

```
loadChildren: () => import('../OtherModules/public-module/public.module').then(({PublicModule}) => PublicModule)
```

Comment: My ESLint requires that we add a type to all anonymous functions (and not the `any` type).

So in your example, I have modified to be:

`loadChildren: (): Promise<PublicModule> => import('../OtherModules/public-module/public.module').then(({PublicModule: PublicModule}) => PublicModule)`

However, I get an error:  "TS2322: Type  Promise<PublicModule>  is not assignable to type blah blah blah"

Looking at the source code, the return types aren't helpful...

Any ideas?